# Continue to play audio even if the screen is locked

Tags: android

I am just messing around with an app that streams audio and I wanted to give it a feature similar to Pandora/Google Music/etc where if you press home or lock the screen the audio continues to play in the background.

How exactly can I accomplish this? Is it through a broadcast receiver or a service? If I knew more closely what I was looking for Google would be more helpful.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a service.  Anytime you want to do something that takes a lot of time like playing music, downloading a lot of data from a server, etc. it should be a service.  The basic technique is to always have the service play the music and then have your activity connect to it to show the status and update the tracks, etc.